# who is responsible for jwt token verification?

Tags: oauth-2.0

when client requests resource with jwt-token, first resource need to verify token. In simple scenario , resource server verifies itself. But there are cases when oauth server is called to verify the token.

So my question is, why oauth server could be called to verify the token?

Answer (score 2):

It all depend's on how you are using validating token. 
Methods used for validating token

---

1. Introspection

> This is a method to get actual token information via special endpoint
>   directly from the Authorization Server. Token information usually
>   includes token type, status (active or not), user, client identifier,
>   available OAuth2 scopes, and expiration time.The method requires
>   direct interaction with Authorization Server for every token
>   validation. It has high safety but low performance.

2. Token validation by signature (JWT tokens only).

> This is a method when the token is validated according to its
>   cryptographic signature and all required token information is received
>   from token itself. It means that token validity is verified without
>   interaction with an Authorization server, and if the token was revoked
>   before its expiration, we’ll never know about it. So, this method is
>   fast but less secure than introspection.

You can have more details on token validation on https://dzone.com/articles/oauth2-tips-token-validation

Comment: so, the only difference between introspection and validation is that we can check whether token was revoked?

Comment: Basically yes, It is one of difference, Introspection guarantees that the token is valid, not expired or revoked.
This approach adds one additional call for each service invocation. It can cause performance problems depending on real system architecture.

Comment: but then who checks token is revoked?

Comment: from your answer i still don't understand the differences. On resource server i can decript token and get all information i need. So what is the difference?